# How to deal with a random eof error while reading on a TCP socket using asio?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, boost-asio, asio

**Scenario:**

This question is to understand what [EOF error](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html#boost_asio.overview.core.streams.why_eof_is_an_error) means and how to deal with it.

I have a client and server written using boost asio 1.64. My applications run pretty well for around 3-4 hours where packets are read back and forth like at least 5 packets sent each second by the server and read by the client application.

**Problem and question:**

But sometimes after a 5-6 hours, I suddenly recieve an eof error! I am not sure what this means. Did the socket get closed for some reason? Can I ignore it and continue reading the next packet? Should I tried this as a connection loss and "re-trigger my connect to peer" logic?

[EOF error](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html#boost_asio.overview.core.streams.why_eof_is_an_error) states - "The end of a stream can cause read, async_read, read_until or async_read_until functions to violate their contract"? But, there have more than 100,000 reads successful before the error appears. What does this indicate? Expecting for some information and understanding about the `eof` error from this question.

Comment: You're misquoting. It doesn't say *you* are violating the read contract. It says that EOF can cause the *read* to violate its contract. EOF simply means that the peer has disconnected. It could be after zero, one, or a million reads. It's up to the peer entirely what it does. You can't ignore it. You have to close the socket. If you're the client you can try reconnecting: if you're the server, just forget about it until the client does so.

Comment: Sorry. If I misquoted unknowingly. I have the exact statement from the official doc which says "The end of a stream can cause read, async_read, read_until or async_read_until functions to violate their contract"

Comment: Exactly. That's what I said it says. The reason for the statement is given in the document. So your question 'how can *I* suddenly violate the read contract?' doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand. Does it mean that I have not violated the contract but just that there is no data to read becuase of some other reason? Can you please state what do you think the reason is for that error when it happens

Comment: I also edited the question about my confusion on violation of contract. I have restated that I just want to understand the probable or exact reasons of the error. Does it mean socket closed? Does it mean that the peer is not sending any more data so there is nothing to read?

Comment: I have already stated the single, exact, reason for the error, and what you have to do about it.

Comment: Ok. it means peer is disconnected. Got it

Comment: Sorry for being a bit stupid. Got it

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, I need to trigger the reconnect logic and I cannot ignore and continue for the next read. Ok got it. Thanks a million.

Comment: Well thanks, glad you got it, but the moral here is read more carefully, isn't it? You didn't really need to go beyond your own citation.